# trigger jquery event from id created in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery event in html, this will be triggered when i press the button from the same html(id of the button is used to trigger jquery). Now I have dynamically created button from javascript(another file) code in the same page. When i press button created from js (with the same id) Jquery is not responding. Please help.

The code looks as below.

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

HTML button:

```
<td width="171" ><div>
 <input type="button" id="opener" value="SelDimn"> </div></td>
```

JS button:

```
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var element5 = document.createElement("input");
element5.type = "button";
element5.setAttribute('id', 'opener');
element5.name = 'opener';
element5.value = 'SelDimn';
cell6.appendChild(element5);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Be careful - it's invalid html to have two elements with the same id.  jQuery selectors will always only return the first one found in the DOM.  (See http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', "#opener", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Also note that ID of an element must be unique, so if there are more than 1 button with the said ID then that is invalid, so you will need to use class attribute to group the similar buttons

In that case change it to `element5.setAttribute('id', 'opener');` to `element5.className = 'opener';`

then

```
$(document).on('click', ".opener", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Also the dom node creation can be simplified as

```
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
$('<input />', {
    type = 'button',
    'class': 'opener',
    name: 'opener',
    value: 'SelDimn'
}).appendTo(cell6)
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) Working fine. Yes I wil take care of unique id.